# How to handle a CLI error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line-interface

I have a simple CLI, something like:

```
p 'Enter email value'
params[:email] = gets.chomp
```

and I want to handle email validation and if the email is invalid then rerun the previous prompt.

I have method for validating email, that simply returns true or false, something like:

```
p 'Enter email value'
params[:email] = gets.chomp
if email invalid
  'error- invalid email'
```

and again run

```
p 'Enter email value'
params[:email] = gets.chomp
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please use proper capitalization and grammar when asking. SO isn't a discussion list where anything goes, it's an online reference book where grammar counts.

Comment: Do you want to determine if an email address is valid according to the RFC rules, or only whether it's a deliverable address? The first takes a very non-trivial pattern. The second is best done by trying to send an email to that address requesting a response. http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/128421 will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [Regular Expressions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html).

To validate whether the email is a valid one or not, you can use regex like so:

```
def validate_email
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  if email =~ VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
    # Do someting here
  else
    validate_email
  end
end
```

Comment: Regular expressions this simple won't begin to handle the full range of valid Email addresses.

Comment: Yes I know, was just using it as an example. He could go so far as to check the email addresses in MX records.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter this code into `until` loop

```
p 'Enter email value'
params[:email] = gets.chomp
until email invalid do
        p 'Enter email value'
        params[:email] = gets.chomp
end
```

Read more at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm